# Is it possible to focus only one axis of astigmatism?

Tags: human-biology, eyes, optics

When we look at something close, we focus our eyes as a circle. But what if someone has astigmatism and focuses on something close, is it possible for the eyes to "focus" only the axis that needs focusing, thereby getting clear vision without astigmatism? (Provided, of course, that the object is at such a distance that it's possible for the eye muscles to "focus" on it so that that that axis would be focused but the other not.)

Comment: What do you mean by "possible"? If it were something humans are generally capable of I don't think there'd be glasses for astigmatism.

Comment: @BryanKrause Glasses are for general use. Even if a person can play around looking at something for some time until they succeed, that doesn't mean they can walk around doing it at will throughout the day. I'm asking if it's theoretically possible by spending some time looking at something. Not if people can do away with glasses for astigmatism.